# (q/kdb+) Interpolation formula not working for some cases

Tags: kdb

I have the formulas below to generate a linear interpolation in q:

```
lsfit:{(enlist y) lsq x xexp/: til 1+z};
interp:{[xn;x;y]sum (1;xn)*flip lsfit[x;y;1]};
```

and the data below to interpolate:

```
xn:(4.7;7.5;4.9);
x:(3 5f;7.5 7.5;3 5f);
y:(1.3 1.5;2 2f;1.3 1.5);
interp'[xn;x;y]
```

which is generating

```
index   value
0   enlist 1.47
1   enlist 0nf
2   enlist 1.49
```

why am I getting `0` in the second row?

**Update:** Inconsistet behaviour for other examples

```
xn:(6;7;8;9);
x:(6 6f;7 7f;8 8f;9 9f);
y:(1 1f;1 1f;1 1f;1 1f);
interp'[xn;x;y]
```

generates

```
index   value
0   enlist 1f
1   enlist 0nf
2   enlist 0nf
3   enlist 1f
```

So, it looks like sometimes the formula works, rows 0 and 3, and sometimes it does not, rows 1 and 2.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are encountering this issue is because of the mathematical details matrix division.

Matrix division can be performed by taking the inverse of a matrix and then matrix multiplying. In q, this can be seen by performing those operations directly.

```
q) enlist[2 2f] lsq (1 2f;3 4f)
-1 1
q) enlist[2 2f] mmu inv (1 2f;3 4f)
-1 1
```

One of your input `x` values to `lsfit` is the row `7.5 7.5`. With a `z` value of `1f`, this converts that vector into a matrix `(1 1;7.5 7.5)` in the `xexp` operation. This matrix is then used in the `lsq` operation.

The problem then occurs because `(1 1;7.5 7.5)` is not invertible. A matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is non-zero. The determinant for a `2 x 2` matrix is `AD - BC`. In your example, `A = 1`, `B = 1`, `C = 7.5`, and `D = 7.5`. So the determinant is zero, the matrix is not invertible, and the output from the function is `Onf`.

To resolve this issue, you would have to ensure that the two items in each row of `x` are not identical.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on how to fix it? Maybe amending the linear interpolation formula?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to do it. I think the problem is that (in the case of index 0) you are trying to perform interpolation between two identical points. I could be wrong, but it seems to me if you only have one unique data point you really can't say anything about any new points. I suspect you should set up a conditional statement at the start of a function to return a warning if your x list contains only one unique value. Otherwise, you could increase the number of data points until you have at least two unique ones, or (if your situation allows it) assume (0,0) is a valid point.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention this in my original post, but the explanation I gave for the `lsq` function (involving the invertibility of the matrices) only applies in the case of square matrices. It is possible to perform matrix division with `lsq` on non-square matrices even though only square matrices are invertible. For all matrices `y`, the `x lsq y` expression is only valid if `y` has linearly independent rows (and a few other conditions, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/matrixes/#lsq). A square matrix that meets this condition is invertible. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Can you take a look at my Update? it looks like that even when points are identical, sometimes the interpolation works.

Comment: I think that there are two questions to answer here. The first is why do indices 0 and 3 in your updated example produce the correct answer. I would argue that the answers they provide are in fact incorrect. Lets take the example of the first row of your result. Suppose, instead of interpolating to `6f`, you interpolate `7f`. The result you get from ```q)interp[7;6 6f;1 1f]``` is ```1.125```. Although this result looks fine, given that it is a non null float, it is no more correct than any other result because you only used one point to construct the line for interpolation.

Comment: From the example above, I don't know why the interpolation gives the correct answer when `6f` is the target x value for interpolation, though I suspect it has to do with the underlying algorithms for calculating matrix division.

Comment: The second question is why do some of the interpolation tests return null, while others do not. For all of the lines in your updated example, the `lsq` function is being run on invalid input. For example, in the first row of your updated example the `lsq` expression becomes `enlist[1 1f] lsq (1 1f;6 6f)`. The right hand side matrix is linearly dependent, and as per the specification for the `lsq` function, the right hand side matrix must have linearly independent rows.

Comment: I don't know for sure why some of the inputs to the `lsq` function are producing null floats while others are not, however I suspect it has to do with floating point arithmetic and whatever underlying algorithms are being used in the `lsq` function. Whenever you deal with floats, there is the problem of dealing with the inherit imprecision of floating point numbers (see https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/precision/#float-precision for more details), and this may lead to the different results. I hope that helps answer your question. Sorry I can't give a more concrete answer.